# Symfony 4 Form not being sent to the DB, probable datetimepicker issue

Tags: forms, symfony, submit, datetimepicker, symfony4

i have this form that was working until i added a datetimepicker. Now the submit button doesn't even work, nothing gets sent to the DB. Would anyone have an idea as to why? Thank you!

I don't get the infamous red bar, no errors are being reported by symfony...

controller

```
 public function newReservation(request $request)
    {

        $reservation = new Contact();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Contact::class);

        $form = $this->createForm(ReservationType::class, $reservation,array());

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $reservation->setName($form['name']->getData());
            $reservation->setContent($form['content']->getData());

            $reservation->setParticipant($form['kidNumber']->getData()+$form['adultNumber']->getData());

            $reservation->setReservationStart($form['reservationStart']->getData());

            $reservation->setReservationEnd($form['reservationEnd']->getData());

            $reservation->setReservationStart2($form['reservation_start2']->getData());

            $reservation->setReservationEnd2($form['reservation_end2']->getData());

            $reservation->setContactName($form['contactName']->getData());

            $reservation->setEmail($form['email']->getData());

            $reservation->setPhone($form['phone']->getData());

            $reservation->setSubject($form['subject']->getData());

            $reservation->setDateSubmit(new \DateTime());
            $reservation->setKidNumber($form['kidNumber']->getData());

            $reservation->setAdultNumber($form['adultNumber']->getData());

            $reservation->setAddress($form['address']->getData());
            $reservation->setStatus('En attente');

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($reservation);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'notice',
                'Demande envoyée'
            );

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
        }

        return $this->render('reservation/reservation.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'reservation' => $reservation
        )
    );

    }
```

form

```
class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('subject', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Subject::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Choisir un type de réservation',
            'placeholder' => ' ',
        ])

        ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label'=>'Organisme', 'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'form-control',
              'title' => 'Organisme',
        )))

       ->add('contactName', TextType::class, array('label'=>'Nom de la personne à contacter', 'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'title' => 'Organisme',
      )))

        ->add('reservationStart', DateTimeType::class, array(
        'label'=>'Date de début - Premier choix',
        'time_widget'=> 'single_text',
        'date_widget'=>'single_text',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'datetimepicker',
            'data-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:ii',
            'title' => 'Save',
        )))

        ->add('reservationEnd', DateTimeType::class, array(
            'label'=>'Date de fin - Premier choix',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'datetimepicker',
                'title' => 'Save',
        )))

        ->add('reservation_start2', DateTimeType::class, array(
            'label'=>'Date de début - Second choix',
            'time_widget'=> 'single_text',
            'date_widget'=>'single_text',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'datetimepicker',
                'title' => 'Save',
        )))

        ->add('reservation_end2', DateTimeType::class, array(
            'label'=>'Date de fin - Second choix',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'datetimepicker',
                'title' => 'Save',
        )))

        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label'=>'Email', 'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'title' => 'Email',
        )))

        ->add('kidNumber', IntegerType::class, array('label'=>'Nombre d\'enfants', 'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'title' => 'Nombre d\'enfant',
        )))

        ->add('adultNumber', IntegerType::class, array('label'=>'Nombre d\'adultes', 'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'title' => 'Nombre d\'adulte',
            )))

        ->add('phone', TelType::class, array('label'=>'Téléphone', 'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'title' => 'Telephone',
            )))

        ->add('address', TextType::class, array('label'=>'Adresse', 'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'title' => 'Adresse',
            )))

        ->add('content', TextareaType::class, array('label'=>'Donnez nous plus d\'informations', 'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'form-control',
              'title' => 'Content',
            )));

        $builder
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Envoyer la demande!',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-margin',
                    'title' => 'Faire une demande'
                )
            ));

    }
}
```

I can't see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a lot to improve in your code. You are using Symfony 4.x, but you are still using old practices.

- Use **Dependency Injection**. Inject what you need. In your case:

  `public function newReservation(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em){...}`
- If you pass class to form, you don't need to set each value to your object. Use `configureOptions()` method and set **data_class** as `Contact::class` (see more details https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html)
- This is **not** how you get `EntityManager`:

  `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Contact::class);`
- If you use previous listed item, you don't need to pass second and third argument:

  `$form = $this->createForm(ReservationType::class, $reservation,array());`

Where's your validation? Have you installed `profiler` (web dev bar)?